# Crear función que abre un cuadro (panel) y que ESPERE a que el boton "btn_GuardarDato" sea apretado y envie el dato (C# Windows Form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms, datatables

Tengo que enviar información desde un DataGridView, el cual debería tener todos los datos cargados. Si falta algún dato, debería mostrar un panel o cuadro, donde doy al usuario la oportunidad de escribir el dato y apretar el botón para enviarlo a donde debe ir.
Tengo una función que abre ese panel.

**Problema:** Al abrir el panel, el código sigue y no espera a que el usuario envié el dato.

**Que necesito:** de alguna forma, abrir el panel que yo he creado y que el código espere a que el dato sea enviado correctamente. Una vez enviado, sigue ejecutándose normalmente.

**Un ejemplo:** un claro ejemplo es un MessageBox.Show(), que se muestra y hasta que no se cierra el cuadro de dialogo, el código queda de alguna manera esperando a que se cierre el cuadro.

**Aclaración:** La 1ra función llama a la función del panel. La función del panel debería llamar una función la cual debe esperar a que termine *(termina al enviar el dato)*. Una vez enviado el dato terminar y volver a la función del panel. Ahora cerrar el panel y volver a la primera función. (Son muchos datos que estoy pidiendo y deben ser ingresados).

Lógica de como lo vengo haciendo:

'''   C#

```
private void LeerDatos(){  
    pos_DGV = DGV_Info.Rows[nroFila].Column('NombreColumna').Value;  
    // nro OC (Deberia agregar columna ID)  
    AgregarValorColumna("Orden de Compra", indice);  
    Factura.InternalId = DGV_Info.Rows[indice].Cells["Orden de Compra"].Value.ToString();  

}  

private void AgregarDatos_DGV(int nroFila, string NombreColumna){  
    // Toma el valor y si es vacio se le pide el valor al usuario
    valorDado = "";
    valorDado = DGV_Info.Rows[nroFila].Cells[nombreColumna].Value.ToString().Trim();

    // Aca debe preguntar si valorDato es != de vacio, si lo es, envia el dato, 
    // pero SINO, abrir el panel y esperar a que el dato sea enviado a traves del boton del panel. 
    // Luego cerrar el panel, y volver a la funcion inicial.
}
```

'''

Comment: Por si alguien quiere probar, les comento lo que tengo para poder ejecutar el código:
Necesito tener columnas en mi DGV (pueden ser vacías), la idea es que estén vacías para probar la función del panel.
Crear un botón que envié la información, y cuando lee una posición, si la posición es vacia, llama a una funcion que abre el panel.
El panel tiene que pedir el dato, mostrar un TextBox y un botón que es el que envía la información.
El problema es que al hacerlo así, el código sigue. Pero debería esperar a enviar el dato primero.

Comment: Debes agregar un [MCVE], con énfasis en **mínimo**, recuerda que tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver que el gridview ni con los datos que procesas